# Creating Bitmap from Webview with content offscreen Android

Tags: android, webview, bitmap

I have a webview that I want to turn into a bitmap for another part of my application.

Currently, I can get a bitmap of the portion of the webview that will be rendered onscreen, however my bitmap needs to contain all of the page's contents.

Setting the webview's layoutParams to a larger size results in the original image loading onto a larger canvas.

Here is my current implementation:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams tempParams= new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(2000,4000);
_webView.setLayoutParams(tempParams);
_webView.layout(0,0,2000,4000);
int width = _webView.getWidth();
int height = _webView.getHeight();

_webView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(_webView.getWidth(), _webView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        _webView.draw(canvas);

    }
},100);
```

I have followed the following tutorials and they do not seem to resolve my issue.

[Rendering Android webview to bitmap, html5 javascript , callback issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10009265/rendering-android-webview-to-bitmap-html5-javascript-callback-issue)

[Generate bitmap from HTML in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633988/generate-bitmap-from-html-in-android)

I was thinking about using a PictureListener and capturePicture() but those have been deprecated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set WebView height to `wrap_contents`, and it will resize itself to the content height.

You can still use `PictureListener.onNewPicture()` to receive a signal that WebView has drawn something. It is better than using `onPageFinished()`, as the latter only indicates that WebView has received all the page contents. The current status of `PictureListener.onNewPicture()` means that it's just not possible to obtain the picture from it, you need to use `WebView.draw()` as you are already doing.

Also, be aware that if your app is targeting L API level or above, you need to call `WebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw()` prior to creating any WebViews in order to make it to draw the entire contents of WebView onto the canvas, see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw()).

Comment: Thanks for the response! Where should I be setting the WebView height to wrap_contents? I am currently using a custom WebView that I did not design, so once I'm done getting my image the WebView's attributes need to be restored.

Comment: Definitely before you are about to load something into it. The same code as you are already using, just use `WRAP_CONTENT` constant instead of a specific height value.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I still get the part of the webview that would have already been displayed on my device, not the entire web page. Thanks though.

Comment: If you have your WebView on screen, did you put it inside a `ScrollView`? Because otherwise, WebView just can't grow beyond the screen size.

Comment: I was targeting below API 21 but testing on a device running above that so once I enabled WebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw() things started working out. Thanks again!